# Failing to use .toJson() function on a List with maps in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list made up of maps in the following format below

```
List<dynamic> data = [];


 data = [
  {'name': 'Name', type: 'STRING',},
  {'name': 'Age', type: 'INTEGER'},
  {'name': 'Weight', type: 'FLOAT'},
  {'name': 'IsMagic', type: 'BOOLEAN'},
];
```

I am trying to send it over the internet in JSON format by using the  .toJson() but i keep getting the error

```
The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
```

this was how i went about it

```
Future creatingTable() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://us-central1-denance-cbf3f.cloudfunctions.net/api/create_table');
    var response =
        await http.post(
            url,
            body: data.toJson(),
            headers: < String, String > {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
        );
    print(
        'Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print(
        'Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

how do i resolve the problem?

Comment: There is no `method` called `toJson()` from the class `List`. Checkout [List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-convert-object-to-json-string/

Answer (score 1):

You should `import 'dart:convert'` and use `jsonEncode(data)`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Future creatingTable() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://us-central1-denance-cbf3f.cloudfunctions.net/api/create_table');
    var response =
        await http.post(
            url,
            body: jsonEncode(data),
            headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
            },
        );
    print(
        'Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print(
        'Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jsonEncode from *dart:convert*

```
List<dynamic> data = [];

data = [
   {'name': 'Name', 'type': 'STRING',},
   {'name': 'Age', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
   {'name': 'Weight', 'type': 'FLOAT'},
   {'name': 'IsMagic', 'type': 'BOOLEAN'},
];

dynamic body = jsonEncode(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error says it all. List class doesn't have `toJson` method defined in it. `toJson` and `fromJson` methods are functions that we define to regarding classes as developers. For example an entity like `Car` can have these methods.

```
class Car {
  final String brand;

  Car({this.brand});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'brand': brand};

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
    Car(brand: json['brand']);
}
```

For your question's answer, if you want to pass the array directly as a json, what you can do is pass data to `jsonEncode` function from `dart:convert` and it will convert your array to json string. Usage: `jsonEncode(data)`.